# Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.EDOfficeLib' or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've faced with this problem when deploying the web site on Windows Server 2008 x64. I don't have any idea. Can anyone help me?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.EDOfficeLib' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.EDOfficeLib' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Interop.EDOfficeLib' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.EDOfficeLib
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Interop.EDOfficeLib | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/TSDX 3.0.0/WebService/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\TSDX 3.0.0\WebService\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\TSDX 3.0.0\WebService\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/9d46c957/8adcacab/Interop.EDOfficeLib.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/9d46c957/8adcacab/Interop.EDOfficeLib/Interop.EDOfficeLib.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/TSDX 3.0.0/WebService/bin/Interop.EDOfficeLib.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.



Stack Trace: 


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.EDOfficeLib' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +192
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +123

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.EDOfficeLib' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11568160
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +485
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +79
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +337
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +280
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1167

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.EDOfficeLib' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11700896
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4869125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running your application written for AnyCPU on a 64bit operating system and one or more of your referenced assemblies is not compiled/available for an x64 system.

The first solution is to recompile your application for x86 platform.
The second solution is to distribute a specific x64 version of the `EDOfficeLib`

Comment: I literally broke my head, and the solution was so simple. Thank you very very very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have to add that in addition my problem can be solved by the following way: Should set an `Enable 32-Bit Applications` parameter to `True` on an Advanced Settings panel of an Application Pool. (IIS Manager). In this case I don't need to recompile something. Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

Comment: Woooooooooooooooo Thank you. I had this to false even after compiling for x86 i sitll got the error. Thanks!